# Shopify liquid array intersection

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to check if a customer has multiple tags assigned. For example:

```
customer.tags = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g'
```

tags to:

```
check = ' a,c,g'
```

I was trying something link this:

```
{% for customer_tag_from_input in customer_tag_from_input_array %}
    {% if customer.tags contains customer_tag_from_input %}
        // Do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this code stops after the first tag is true and doesn't continue checking if the other tags are present.